# Ajax jQuery with FormData and string values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to pass a jQuery AJAX request that contains both a FormData object as well as a string value? Below are my unsuccessful attempts so far. I keep getting the same error:

> Undefined index: check

when I attempt to fetch the value like this:

```
$test = $_POST['check'];
echo $test;
```

My two attempts are as seen below:

```
var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('#form1'));
var bar = "salesReport";

$.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', 
        url         : 'process.php',
        data        : {
                        formData,
                        check : bar
                            }, 
        dataType    : 'json', 
        processData : false,
        contentType : false,
        encode      : true
    })
```

or this:

```
var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('#form1'));

formData.append("check", "salesReport");

$.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', 
        url         : 'process.php',
        data        : formData,
        dataType    : 'json', 
        processData : false,
        contentType : false,
        encode      : true
    })
```

Comment: Do you use a php backend?

Comment: @Mazz Yes I do have a PHP backend.

Comment: could you try to print_r(file_get_contents('php://input'));

Answer (score 0):

If you have a php backend you may have to parse it from the input stream

```
$request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$_POST = (array)(json_decode($request_body, true));
```

then you can use the $_POST again

Comment: What do you get when you print_r($_POST)

Comment: and also console.log(formData)